# How to fix "PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_ldap.so)" in SLES 15 SP4?

Tags: pam, ldap, sles

Somehow I ended up in SLES 15 with error messages like this:

> (systemd)[6729]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_ldap.so): /lib64/security/pam_ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However I'm not sure what lead to that situation, and also I'm unsure how to fix it, because there is no RPM with `pam_ldap.so` it seems.

The system had been upgraded from SLES 12 SP5 via SLES 15 SP3 to SLES 15 SP4.

Obviously LDAP client configuration was intended and once worked, but it does not at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From [Changelog for SLES 15 SP4](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/15-SP4/changelog.html), it would seem that `pam_ldap` has been removed. I assume you need to go `pam_sss` which does have LDAP support.

Comment: You are right that the packages were removed. However the changelog is very poor, and most of all: Shouldn't an enterprise product like SLES be smarter when upgrading, rather than leaving an invalid configuration behind? Still your answer could be more verbose to be helpful, actually.